# Errors on font change to site

Tags: php, sass, opencart

On the site, which is made on the Opencart theme, which allows you to change the font in the theme control panel. But, when I have a standard font on "Ralewey" (it is in the theme directory) I get Opencart such an error and does not change the font. Can you please tell me how to fix it and still change the font to the desired one?

This is the error that the server gives me.
**Errors:**

```
Warning: include_once(/home/us392481/volkhovskiy.com/storage/vendor/scss.inc.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/us392481/volkhovskiy.com/www/admin/model/plaza/sass.php on line 5Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '/home/us392481/volkhovskiy.com/storage/vendor/scss.inc.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/pear/php73') in /home/us392481/volkhovskiy.com/www/admin/model/plaza/sass.php on line 5
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Scssc' not found in /home/us392481/volkhovskiy.com/www/admin/model/plaza/sass.php:67 Stack trace: #0 /home/us392481/volkhovskiy.com/storage/modification/system/engine/loader.php(248): ModelPlazaSass->compileData(Array) #1 /home/us392481/volkhovskiy.com/www/system/engine/proxy.php(47): Loader->{closure}(Array, Array) #2 /home/us392481/volkhovskiy.com/www/admin/controller/extension/module/ptcontrolpanel.php(17): Proxy->__call('compileData', Array) #3 /home/us392481/volkhovskiy.com/storage/modification/system/engine/action.php(79): ControllerExtensionModulePtcontrolpanel->index() #4 /home/us392481/volkhovskiy.com/www/admin/controller/startup/router.php(26): Action->execute(Object(Registry), Array) #5 /home/us392481/volkhovskiy.com/storage/modification/system/engine/action.php(79): ControllerStartupRouter->index() #6 /home/us392481/volkhovskiy.com/www/system/engine/router.php(67): Action->execute(Object(Registry)) #7 /home/us392481/volkhovskiy.com/www/system/engine/router.php(56): Router->e in /home/us392481/volkhovskiy.com/www/admin/model/plaza/sass.php on line 67
```

This is the file that is mentioned in the error.
**sass.php:**

```
<?php
class ModelPlazaSass extends Model
{
    public function compileData($data) {
        include_once(DIR_STORAGE . 'vendor/scss.inc.php');
 
        $this->load->model('setting/store');
        $this->load->model('setting/setting');
 
        $stores[] = array(
            'store_id' => 0,
            'name'     => $this->config->get('config_name') . $this->language->get('text_default')
        );
 
        foreach ($this->model_setting_store->getStores() as $store) {
            $stores[] = array(
                'store_id' => $store['store_id'],
                'name'     => $store['name']
            );
        }
 
        foreach ($stores as $store) {
            // Detech Directory By Store
            $theme = $this->model_setting_setting->getSettingValue('config_theme', $store['store_id']);
            $theme_directory_code = "theme_" . $theme . '_directory';
            $directory = $this->model_setting_setting->getSettingValue($theme_directory_code, $store['store_id']);
 
            $file = DIR_CATALOG . 'view/theme/' . $directory . '/stylesheet/plaza/theme.css';
 
            // Body
            $body_font_family = $data['module_ptcontrolpanel_body_font_family_name'][$store['store_id']];
            $body_font_cate = $data['module_ptcontrolpanel_body_font_family_cate'][$store['store_id']];
            $body_font_link = $data['module_ptcontrolpanel_body_font_family_link'][$store['store_id']];
            $body_font_size = $data['module_ptcontrolpanel_body_font_size'][$store['store_id']];
            if(!$body_font_size) $body_font_size = "14px";
            $body_font_weight = $data['module_ptcontrolpanel_body_font_weight'][$store['store_id']];
            $body_font_color = $data['module_ptcontrolpanel_body_color'][$store['store_id']];
 
            // Heading
            $heading_font_family = $data['module_ptcontrolpanel_heading_font_family_name'][$store['store_id']];
            $heading_font_cate = $data['module_ptcontrolpanel_heading_font_family_cate'][$store['store_id']];
            $heading_font_link = $data['module_ptcontrolpanel_heading_font_family_link'][$store['store_id']];
            $heading_font_weight = $data['module_ptcontrolpanel_heading_font_weight'][$store['store_id']];
            $heading_font_color = $data['module_ptcontrolpanel_heading_color'][$store['store_id']];
 
            // Link
            $link_color = $data['module_ptcontrolpanel_link_color'][$store['store_id']];
            $link_hover_color = $data['module_ptcontrolpanel_link_hover_color'][$store['store_id']];
 
            // Button
            $button_color = $data['module_ptcontrolpanel_button_color'][$store['store_id']];
            $button_hover_color = $data['module_ptcontrolpanel_button_hover_color'][$store['store_id']];
            $button_bg_color = $data['module_ptcontrolpanel_button_bg_color'][$store['store_id']];
            $button_bg_hover_color = $data['module_ptcontrolpanel_button_bg_hover_color'][$store['store_id']];
 
            // Custom
            $custom_css = $data['module_ptcontrolpanel_custom_css'][$store['store_id']];
 
            $css_line = "@import url(". $body_font_link .");";
            $css_line .= "@import url(". $heading_font_link .");";
            $css_line .= "body { font-family: '". $body_font_family ."', ". $body_font_cate ."; font-size: ". $body_font_size ."; font-weight: ". $body_font_weight ."; color: #". $body_font_color ."; }";
            $css_line .= "h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { font-family: '". $heading_font_family ."', ". $heading_font_cate ."; font-weight: ". $heading_font_weight ."; color: #". $heading_font_color ."; }";
            $css_line .= "a { color: #". $link_color ."; } a:hover { color: #". $link_hover_color ."; }";
            $css_line .= "button,.btn,.btn-primary { color: #". $button_color ."; background-color: #". $button_bg_color ."; border-color: #". $button_bg_color .";background-image: none;} button:hover,.btn:hover,.btn-primary:hover,.btn-primary.disabled,.btn-primary.disabled.active,.btn-primary.disabled.focus,.btn-primary.disabled:active,.btn-primary.disabled:focus,.btn-primary.disabled:hover,.btn-primary[disabled],.btn-primary[disabled].active,.btn-primary[disabled].focus,.btn-primary[disabled]:active,.btn-primary[disabled]:focus,.btn-primary[disabled]:hover,fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary,fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary.active,fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary.focus,fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary:active,fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary:focus,fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary:hover,.btn-primary.active.focus, .btn-primary.active:focus, .btn-primary.active:hover, .btn-primary:active.focus, .btn-primary:active:focus, .btn-primary:active:hover, .open>.dropdown-toggle.btn-primary.focus, .open>.dropdown-toggle.btn-primary:focus, .open>.dropdown-toggle.btn-primary:hover { color: #". $button_hover_color ."; background-color: #". $button_bg_hover_color ."; border-color: #". $button_bg_hover_color ."; }";
            $css_line .= $custom_css;
 
            $scss = new Scssc();
            $scss->setImportPaths(DIR_CATALOG . 'view/theme/' . $directory . '/stylesheet/sass/');
            $scss->setFormatter('scss_formatter_compressed');
 
            $output = $scss->compile($css_line);
 
            $handle = fopen($file, 'w');
 
            flock($handle, LOCK_EX);
 
            fwrite($handle, $output);
 
            fflush($handle);
 
            flock($handle, LOCK_UN);
 
            fclose($handle);
        }
    }
}
```

If you need the code of any other files, write it.

Comment: Link on errors is closed. Place errors in your question.

Comment: I added an error.

Comment: Does this file exists */home/us392481/volkhovskiy.com/storage/vendor/scss.inc.php*?

Comment: Yes, but only this file has a different path: _/home/us392481/volkhovskiy.com/storage/vendor/scssphp/scssphp/scss.inc.php_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply correct the path to your **scss.inc.php**

Try to replace this

```
include_once(DIR_STORAGE . 'vendor/scss.inc.php');
```

with this

```
include_once(DIR_STORAGE . 'vendor/scssphp/scssphp/scss.inc.php');
```

---

Or just copy file **scss.inc.php** directly into */home/us392481/volkhovskiy.com/storage/vendor/*

Comment: In this case, even more, errors occur: https://ideone.com/57FuDt

Answer (score 1):

You will have to comment IF condition in the sass.php file.

Open the file /admin/controller/startup/sass.php and edited the file sass.php.

```
// if (!is_file($file) || !$this->config->get('developer_sass')) {
        //  include_once(DIR_STORAGE . 'vendor/scss.inc.php');          
        //  $scss = new Scssc();
        //  $scss->setImportPaths(DIR_APPLICATION . 'view/stylesheet/sass/');
        //  $output = $scss->compile('@import "_bootstrap.scss"');
        //  $handle = fopen($file, 'w');
        //  flock($handle, LOCK_EX);
        //  fwrite($handle, $output);
        //  fflush($handle);
        //  flock($handle, LOCK_UN);
        //  fclose($handle);
        // }
```